# javascript object in undefined error in server but not in localhost

Tags: javascript

My JSON object:

```
var projects = {
  "id_1": {
    "category": "Residential",
    "name": "Optima Upgrade",
    "area_id": "14916",            
    "bedrooms": "1.5 BHK, 2 BHK, 2.5 BHK, 3 BHK"
  },
  "id_4": {
    "category": "Residential",
    "name": "Optima Ace",
    "area_id": "12508",
    "bedrooms": "1 BHK, 2 BHK"
  }
}
```

My JavaScript code:

```
var projectid = [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" ];

jQuery.each( projectid, function( i, val ) {
  id = 'id_'+val;
  if(projects[id]['category']==="Land")       
    // do stmt
  } else if(projects[id]['category']==="Residential") {
    // do stmt
  }
```

I get this error on the live server:

```
TypeError: projects[id] is undefined
```

But no error on localhost.

Comment: Please include a complete example of what is happening in the version on the server. Because the error is quite explicit in what the problem is. So Are you loading the file that contains the projects from another source? or perhaps it's merely not yet loaded when you run the other part? Please give more details.

Comment: are you sure projects have two objects? check its length first and also change your if condition `if(typeof projects[id]!='undefined'&& projects[id]['category']==="Land") {`

Comment: Can it be that this error is generated when the loop iteration hits something other than 1 or 4? in that case it does not find any such element and hence the error.

Comment: updated in the question @EWit

Comment: so as updates question you have to check for `undefined` just like `if(typeof projects[id]!='undefined'&& projects[id]['category']==="Land") {}` as same for second condition

Comment: check this: http://jsfiddle.net/n1p77jnw/

Comment: strange.. thanks all for solve this issue.. special thanks to @Learner